# Describing the distribution of N points in D-dimensional space?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition

I want to tackle a classification problem by describing the samples as its descriptors' distributions.

So let's say each sample has a label, and $N$ vectors of dimension $D$, (N and D are fixed) and I want to describe their distributions numerically. I think this problem is similar to shape matching. However, I do not have a reference "shape", so I also have to learn the reference shape for each class.

Another difficulty is that the N "interest points" are not necessarily ordered. So I cannot treat them as points in $ND$-dimensional space, without ordering / matching them.

So are there any solutions to such a problem? Can you guide me in the correct direction for learning and matching the distributions of the points?

Comment: What do you mean by "describe numerically"? Would a kernel density estimate be good enough? What about a density estimate based on projection coefficients, which (for a fixed basis) gives you a vector out?

Comment: @Dougal I'm not sure what those terms mean but probably they are what I'm looking for. I want to use the shapes as descriptors for a pattern classification problem.

Comment: Okay! It turns out this is a nonstandard problem, but one that I've worked on. :) Can you give a general idea of about how big $N$ and $D$ are, as well as how many total patterns you have? It affects the answer a lot.

Comment: D could vary between 10 and 10.000 really. it depends on the descriptor I use. But usually it's in the order of 1000. N will be very small, 3 to 5.

Comment: Describing a 10,000 dimensional distribution with 3-5 samples is pretty hopeless; even a 10d one is not going to work well. Can you describe the problem a little more? There's probably another way to frame it that'll work better.

Comment: It is not 3-5 samples. it is 3-5 (10k-dimensional) points per sample.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant – "sample" is an overloaded word that can mean either a set or a single point. Do you think that each sample set is from a single consistent "shape", and so the problem can be thought of as, given $N$ points from a shape, determine which class shape it came from?

Comment: The shape consists of N points. So each sample is an NxD matrix, and yes I want to determine which class this ND matrix comes from.

Comment: I think you'll probably need to assume that the distributions from a given class are all (nearly) the same. If that's not true, or there's not some other special structure, I'm skeptical you'll be able to do anything with only 5 samples.

Comment: Yes my assumption is that the shapes are similar for same classes. What I'm actually doing is I'm applying a k-means clustering for multiple descriptors in a sample (assuming each sample has at leas k descriptors). So I'm using only the centers, i.e. the k D-dimensional descriptors. And I want to analyse the distributions of these centers.